# SVM cost function: old and new definitions

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, data-mining, loss-functions

I am trying to reconcile different definitions of the soft-margin SVM cost / loss function in primal form. **There is a "max()" operator that I do not understand.**

I learned about SVM many years ago from the undergraduate-level textbook "[Introduction to Data Mining](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/index.php)" by Tan, Steinbach, and Kumar, 2006. It describes the soft-margin primal form SVM cost function in Chapter 5, p. 267-268. Note that there is no mention of a max() operator.

> This can be done by introducing positive-valued slack variables ($\xi$)
>   into the constraints of the optimization problem. ...
>   The modified objective function is given by the following equation:
>
> $ f(\mathbf{w}) = \frac{\left \| \mathbf{w} \right \|^2}{2} + C(\sum_{i=1}^{N} \xi)^k $
>
> where $C$ and $k$ are user-specified parameters representing the penalty
>   of misclassifying the training instances. For the remainder of this
>   section, we assume $k$ = 1 to simplify the problem. The parameter $C$ can be
>   chosen based on the model's performance on the validation set.
>
> It follows that the Lagrangian for this constrained optimization
>   problem can be written as follows:
>
> $ L_{p} = \frac{\left \| \mathbf{w} \right \|^2}{2} + C(\sum_{i=1}^{N}
> \xi)^k - \sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda_i (y_i (\mathbf{w} \cdot \mathbf{x_i} 
> + b) - 1 + \xi_i) - \sum_{i=1}^{N} \mu_i \xi_i $
>
> where the first two terms are the objective function to be minimized,
>   the third term represents the inequality constraints associated with
>   the slack variables, and the last term is the result of the
>   non-negativity requirements on the values of the $\xi_i$'s.

So that was from a 2006 textbook.

Now (in 2016), I started reading more recent material on SVM. In the [Stanford class for image recognition](http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#loss), the soft-margin primal form is stated in a much different way:

> Relation to Binary Support Vector Machine. You may be coming to this
>   class with previous experience with Binary Support Vector Machines,
>   where the loss for the i-th example can be written as:
>
> [image: Stanford SVM]

Similarly, on [Wikipedia's article on SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Soft-margin), the loss function is given as:

> [image]

**Where is this "max" function coming from?** Is it contained in the first two formulas in the "Introduction to Data Mining" version? How do I reconcile the old and new formulations? Is that textbook simply out-of-date?

Answer (score 7):

The slack variable $\xi$ is defined as follows (picture from Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning).

[image]

$\xi_i = 1- y_i(\omega x_i+b)$ if $x_i$ is on the wrong side of the margin (i.e., $1- y_i(\omega x_i+b)>0$),
$\xi_i=0$ otherwise.

Thus $\xi_i=max(0, 1- y_i(\omega x_i+b))\qquad(1)$.

So minimizing the first definition subject to constraint (1) $$ f(\mathbf{w}) = \frac{\left \| \mathbf{w} \right \|^2}{2} + C(\sum_{i=1}^{N} \xi)^k $$ is equivalent to minimizing the second definition (regularizer+hinge loss) $$R(w)+C\sum max(0, 1- y_i(\omega x_i+b)).$$

There's another question that might be related [Understanding the constraints of SVMs in the non-separable case?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198256/understanding-the-constraints-of-svms-in-the-non-separable-case).

Comment: can u please explain why zeta_i = 1-yi(wx_i+b) ..if x_i is on the wrong side

Comment: @MilanAmrutJoshi good question, I haven't really thought about it, waiting to see if there's any answer to the question you just posted

Comment: @MilanAmrutJoshi I believe it has something to with the margin, since there's a $||w||^2$ term in the loss, I guess it's equal to "finding the the boundary that the distance of all points on the wrong side to the margin is the smallest"